# Boot Camp but for windows

Tags: macos

Are there any programs similar to boot camp - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_Camp_%28software%29 - but to run mac, on a windows computer?

Comment: Despite the unnecessary downvotes, MarkM's answer is the correct one. I suggest you edit your question to include the Mac OS version intended. Because if it is anything other than Mac OS X Server 10.5, it's an infringement of the Eula and this question should be closed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot run OS X on non-apple hardware without being in violation of OS X's EULA. There are, of course, unsupported and unofficial ways to do this, but it is at your own risk and potentially illegal. The name of one of the biggest projects is called OSX86, but as mentioned earlier - it is potentially illegal and definitely a violation of the EULA.

Comment: If you're going to down-vote accurate information you can at least leave a comment as to why.

Comment: No one's going to do that. They downvote because they don't like the question, that's all. Oh yeah, +1 for a good answer :)

Comment: Yes it's against the EULA, but many tips/hacks in SU are against the product's EULA anyway.

Comment: It is important to note that Apple is suing Psystar, a company distributing non-apple hardware with OS X on it.

Comment: OS X's EULA is invalid and unenforcable in many European countries. (Also, *technically* you can install OS X without violating the EULA, if you simply don't accept the EULA ;-)).

Answer (score 5):

Certainly! There is a big project called OSx86 which involves installing and running OS X on a PC. There are loads of guides and support on the [OSx86 website](http://www.osx86project.org/). Additionally, they do have an IRC support channel which can be good to get some immediate help, and there are forums at [InsanelyMac](http://www.insanelymac.com/) to help you out.

Lifehacker has a pretty in depth and excellent guide on how to [Install Snow Leopard on your Hackintosh PC, no hacking required](http://lifehacker.com/5360150/install-snow-leopard-on-your-hackintosh-pc-no-hacking-required)

But first before you go off and install OS X on your PC, you must be aware of a few things:

- It breaks the EULA. However, the legality and enforceability of a [EULA is debatable](https://superuser.com/questions/30940/is-an-eula-enforceable).
- It is not necessarily illegal, but downloading software (such as modified builds of OS X) IS illegal. The guide from Lifehacker is perfectly legal because it uses a retail version of OS X Snow Leopard
- Hardware support is largely finicky, especially for Snow Leopard. I suggest you go with Leopard for now, as it seems to have the greatest hardware support. You might have to venture onto the internet and find the kexts (drivers for OS X) for any non-working hardware
- If using a modified build of OS X (not a retail disc), you probably won't be able to apply system updates (10.5.x, 10.6.x) without doing preparation before hand. This may also apply to using a retail disc (such as the Lifehacker guide).

Before I bought my Macbook I had OS X running smoothly on my desktop computer fine. Once I looked around on the internet to solve a couple of problems, all hardware in my computer was working fine.

Installing OSx86 is a fun and interesting project, and you have nothing to loose (as long as you backup your data) by giving it a go. I highly suggest it, as long as you have the time.

Comment: You learn a lot from building a hackintosh. I have a better understanding of how the OS works, how I can better customize it and make it fit the way I work thanks to my desire of installing Mac OS on my PC.

Answer (score 1):

You can go the VM way and use VMWare. It supports Mac OS X Server 10.5.

Comment: According to Apple's EULA, Leopard Server can only be virtualized on an existing OS X Server. Kind of a bummer actually.

Comment: Yes. Following the EULA, that shouldn't be done. But...

Comment: Agreed with the but... :) But we should still put that as a disclaimer on any questionable suggestions as we don't know the laws of where other users could live. One country's slap on the wrist is another country's serious violation.

Comment: Editing my answer. It's not proper

Comment: There wasn't anything wrong with your answer, it helped the OP see some options. I just think it's important to note when there may be some questionable legality involved. It's not like we're telling OP tips for hacking a corporate network or DDoSing a major website :)

Answer (score 0):

Install grub (or get someone to help you install grub) from a linux CD.

Comment: How will GRUB let you run OS X on a PC?

Comment: By doing what it's designed for MarkM.

Comment: I didn't realize that GRUB circumvented the TPM check in OS X and also patched OS X to run on BIOS instead of EFI. What version of GRUB were these features added in?

Comment: Lee B, have you ever actually installed OS X on a PC? You don't need to go anywhere near GRUB to get it working.

Comment: Guys, I'm not going to argue with you about whether a bootloader is like a bootloader.  If you don't like my comment, write your own.  I stand by what I've said, and a moment of googling should confirm it for you.

Comment: For what it's worth, he asked "Are there any programs similar to boot camp... but to run mac, on a windows computer?", not "I want to know how to hack OS X and get it running on a PC".  That's a completely different question.

Comment: @Lee B - I think it's pretty clear what the OP is asking. Boot Camp is much more than a boot loader, so your snarky comparison to GRUB is both inaccurate and the wrong answer to the question.

Comment: Well, sorry Mark, but I think you're wrong, and I'm right.  We'll just have to agree to disagree.  Sorry if you can't live with that, but that's your issue, not mine.